# React state variable will not be displayed after changing route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, core-ui

Whenever I go to a new url and then try and go back to the original URL within my application, the state variables do not display. I am using react, react-router and the coreUI template. For example, if I load for the first time my one webpage, I get the following:

[image]

When I go elsewhere in my app and them come back to the same url I get this:

[image]

The data that is loaded is from a test file that I have locally and despite seeing the data in the console, it does not render. Here is a portion of my code:

```
import category_data from './category_data.js';

function processCategories(category, categories) {
  let children = categories.filter( a => category.children.indexOf(a._id) > -1 );
  for(let x = 0; x < children.length; x++) {
    children[x].children = processCategories(children[x], categories);
  }

  children.sort( (a, b) => a.order - b.order);
  return children;
}


class Category extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    if(this.props.category.children.length)  {
      return (
        <>
          <ListItem ml="3" display="block">
          {this.props.category.title}
          </ListItem>
          <List display="block" className="ml-3">
            { this.props.category.children.map( a => <Category category={a} /> ) }
          </List>
        </>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <ListItem ml="3" display="block">
          {this.props.category.title}
        </ListItem>
      )
    }
  }
}

class Deck extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header">
          <i className="icon-note"></i> {this.props.deck.title}
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">
          <Row>
            <List display="block">
              {this.props.deck.children.map( a => <Category category={a} /> )}
            </List>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class DeckDisplay extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      roots: []
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    let roots = [],
      categories = [];

    for(let x = 0; x < category_data.length; x++) {
      if(category_data[x].root) {
        roots.push(category_data[x]);
      } else {
        categories.push(category_data[x]);
      }
    }

    for(let x = 0; x < roots.length; x++) {
      roots[x].children = processCategories(roots[x], categories)
    }

    await this.setState({
      roots: roots
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
        {this.state.roots.map( props => <Deck deck={props} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DeckDisplay;
```

For more information on navigation, you can see [the github repository](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template). Simply navigate to `src/views`.

**Update:**

When I initially load the decks, my roots state is as it should be with all categories nested within eachother. When I come back to the url, the children array is empty.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code. Please improve the code example by adding enough so that we can run it ourselves and see the same results you do. At the moment there is no way to navigate to another view. Also it isn't clear how `this.props.deck` is passed in and there is no definition for `Category` component. You don't need to show the full complexity of your entire app. We just need enough to actually work with in order to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to keep it as brief as possible. I made some additions as you can see above.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by `roots.push(deepClone(category_data[x]))` and `categories.push(deepClone(category_data[x])`. I figured that values are referenced and when the function completes, garbage collection removes categories. I do not understand why that would happen because `category_data.js` simply contains an array of `categories` but it works.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Regarding coder in questions: Brevity is good. And I appreciate you trying to keep the code minimal. At the same time, it needs to run without any errors other than what you ask about. Removing to much of your code often introduces unintended errors. I often find it helpful to start a new project that reproduces the problem I'm trying to solve. Often I'll figure it out before i pay a question.